# How to use same domain (www.example.com) in multiple servers?

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, api, iis-8

I have one application deployed in AWS and another one in windows machine IIS.
I want same domain to be used in both the applications.
Is there any settings in IIS to do so?

Comment: Can you elaborate? Do you want a traffic distribution for the same domain like to on-prem and cloud in a round-robin fashion or so? Or do you want that IIS and AWS resources accessed via different subdomains both under `example.com`. What's your ultimate objective?

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like www.a.example.com for one and www.b.example.com for another which is called subdomain. But its impossible to use one domain www.example.com for multiple sites as you can point a domain name to only one service meaningfully.